# Jenkins build failing due to Maven dependencies not been configured

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus, sonatype

When built a Maven based project on Jenkins it is failing. Asked developers in my project came to know that the dependencies x, y, z were not been built and their jar files are not getting pushed to Nexus repository.

We use Sonatype Nexus, I believe the dependencies were not been configured in either Nexus or on Jenkins.

I am really confused, is it not configured on Jenkins or on Nexus.

My target is to - if the dependencies were really missing - I want to add them up in Nexus.

Below is the scenario:
project = x
dependencies = a, b, c

a,b,c were not built so their jar files are not present in Nexus repo, had these been present there my Jenkins project would have picked them up.

I saw project x in the intended project which I am building on jenkins. 
So, in order for x to pick those dependencies some kind of linkage to be made in Nexus repo with those dependencies a, b, c.

Can anyone please help me or provide me the ways to add the dependencies in Nexus repo

or(and)

provide me the steps to configure a Maven project on Jenkins (Nexus repo should have all the dependencies, so that Jenkins picks them up whenever the project is built).

My question might be confusing but I really want to learn and execute it and make it successful.

I will keep trying in between until I get an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share some logs?

Comment: Please forgive me for not sharing the logs, however they just contain the errors related to missing modules or something, reason being developers commit their code to dependency a or b or c (may be) but project x is not able to pick them up as they were not built at all, as explained their jar files are missing. Someone/Somewhere those dependency's jar files should be included in Nexus repo.. I have very little knowledge on this but trying to amend as far as possible. Thanks..

Comment: can you tell what a,b,c were, is this a project in your workspace or it is a common artifact

Comment: I think they are common artifacts

Comment: if it is a common artifact then it will most probably available in the nexus repository refer http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/06/getting-started-with-nexus-maven-repo-manager/ for pushing an artifact to nexus

Comment: you can also use "mvn deploy" to push artifact

Comment: @Arasu, thanks for your comments.. I guess the tutorial you sent is more into installing Nexus. We have it already installed I just want to know what needs to be done further.

Comment: it also contains how to push a artifact (your artifact) to nexus

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Nexus documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/index.html), the [trial guide](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/eval-proxy-publish.html) and the [Nexus examples project](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples) to see how to configure a Maven project to consume artifacts from Nexus and publish them there. Jenkins will just run the Maven build so that changes nothing. Check out [the episodes about continuous integration setups with Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/members-only/video-gallery-2/free-training-sonatype-nexus-and-clm-tips-from-the-trenches/) to see more tips about Jenkins usage.

Alternatively you [can manually upload a artifact](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html) as well